# Phonegap throws "Network Error" immediately on the first character of PHP script on phone - Works fine in Chrome/Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm hoping for a little help with a rather intractable problem. For starters, I'll explain the problem, because it almost seems like it may be a conceptual one, then I will post some code samples to illustrate.

I have developed an application using HTML and JQuery mobile, using mySQL and PHP for the back-end. I am using phonegap to port it over to the phone. The first page (login page) loads fine on the phone, in chrome, and in DW live view. However, on the phone, when I try to interact with the server in any way (i.e. clicking the login button), I get the following error:

> Network error has occurred
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Now, by eliminating the first "<" character in my php file (i.e. from the "< ?php" starting tag), the error becomes the following, as I expected:

> Network error has occurred:
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?

Since the first character of the script is now "?", it proves the first character of the script is the problem. This clearly demonstrates that phonegap is not playing nice with my PHP implementation, and I have no idea why. Like I mentioned earlier, the application works flawlessy when viewed in Google Chrome browser, or the DW Live view.

I am using JQuery "$.ajax()" function to send AJAX requests to the server, here is the code:

First, a view of the first page of the JQuery mobile (login):

```
<div data-role="page" id="login_page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Login Page2</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="login_form">
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="login_email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="login_email" id="login_email" value=""  />

            <label for="login_pass">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="login_pass" id="login_pass" value=""  />
            
          <h4 id="login_notification"><?php echo 'Notifications will appear here...';  ?></h4>
          <button data-theme="b" id="login_submit" type="button">Login</button>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <center>
            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <a href="#reg_page" data-role="button">Don't have an account? Register here.</a>
            </div>
        </center>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, the relevant Javascript/JQuery:

```
// Login page handler
$(document).on('pageshow', '#login_page', function() {
    $("#login_notification").text("page loaded");
    
    // Check to see if a user account is loaded in, if not create one set to dummy variables
    if (localStorage.getItem("logged_user") === null) {
        var userInfo = {
            "user_id": -1,
            "logged_in": false, 
        };
        localStorage.setItem("logged_user", JSON.stringify(userInfo));
    }
    
    $(document).on('click', '#login_submit', function(){
        $("#login_notification").text("button clicked");
        
        var formData = $("#login_form").serialize();
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // Method of sending data to server
            url: "php_scripts/login_handle.php", // php script being sent to
            cache: false,  // requested pages won't be cached by server
            data: formData, // data to be sent to server
            dataType: "json", // data type to be received back from server
            success: onLoginSuccess, // function to call on success
            error: onError  // function to call on error
        });
        
        return false;
        
        //alert('Testing alert!'); 
    });
});
```

And finally, the PHP script, which I don't think is itself the problem (like I said, i suspect the first character of the script, regardless of what it is, is throwing the error):

```
<?php
    include_once 'db_connect.php';
    
    $valid_login = false;
    $error_msg = '';
    
    // Check to see if necessary fields are set
    if (isset($_POST['login_email'], $_POST['login_pass'])) {
        // Extract data
        $email = $_POST['login_email'];
        $raw_pass = $_POST['login_pass'];
        
        // Check the database to see if the user exists
        $check_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
        if ($check_stmt) {
            if ($check_stmt->bind_param('s', $email)) {
                if ($check_stmt->execute()) {
                    $check_stmt->store_result();
                    // Get variables from result
                    $check_stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
                    $check_stmt->fetch();
                    
                    // Append the salt to the raw password and hash them together
                    $password = hash('sha512', $raw_pass . $salt);
                    
                    // Check if user w/ email address exists
                    if ($check_stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                        // Check to see if passwords match
                        if ($password == $db_password) {
                            // If they do, set login boolean to true
                            $valid_login = true;
                        }else {
                            $error_msg .= 'Invalid email or password';
                        }
                        
                    }else {
                        $error_msg .= 'No user with that email address. ';
                    }
                }else {
                    $error_msg .= 'Database error (execute, prepare). ';
                }
            }else {
                $error_msg .= 'Database error (bind, prepare). ';
            }
        }else {
            $error_msg .= 'Database error (check, prepare). ';
        }
        
    }else {
        $error_msg .= 'Please fill out the required fields. ';
    }
    
    $output = array('valid' => $valid_login, 'error_msg' => $error_msg, 'user_id' => $user_id);
    echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Please, anyone with some phonegap experience, please help me figure out why it's not working! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You've to change the ajax 'url' to the absolute url of the php script that resides on your  webserver. Not a php script inside your phonegap application

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // Method of sending data to server
        url: "http://domain.com/php_scripts/login_handle.php", // php script being sent to
        cache: false,  // requested pages won't be cached by server
        data: formData, // data to be sent to server
        dataType: "json", // data type to be received back from server
        success: onLoginSuccess, // function to call on success
        error: onError  // function to call on error
    });
```

Comment: I just implemented your suggested fix, and it didn't work. I don't think the problem is the ability to find the PHP script, because (as mentioned) when I changed the first character of the script, the error changed along with it, indicating the file was, at the very least, being reached by the program.

Comment: The problem is as that your php file is never interpreted. Therefore you're getting it as it reads, without executing the php code itself. If it would be interpreted it would never give you the '<' or '?' characters

Comment: Exactly! The question is why is it not being interpreted... I'll double check and make sure I used the domain approach right, but I don't think it is the reason...

Comment: Moreover, after changing it to the domain full path, it still works fine in DW and Chrome, indicating that the file is still being found as intended. Just for some reason the Phonegap conversion kills the ability to interpret the PHP script?

Comment: Do you think I have to use jsonp instead of json as the data return type? That would explain why it works on the browser (which is pulling all the files from the server) and not from the phone (which is hosting most files on the phone)...

I'm going to try to implement that now.

Comment: You can .php files on the phone? You have to host the .php files on a webserver that can interpret .php files and serve them over http